# Falha 'AUTORIDADE NT\LOGON ANÔNIMO' no SQL Server 2012 em servidor remoto

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012

Tenho uma aplicação funcionando legal no meu servidor local. Fiz algumas alterações nela e me preparei para publicar um ambiente de homologação para testes. Como estamos migrando os bancos e servidores locais para um novo `data center`, resolvi testar a nova aplicação já apontando para o banco no novo *data center*. A questão é que agora, ao mudar minha *connection string* para o novo servidor e banco, ao rodar a aplicação no Visual Studio obtenho o seguinte erro:

```
Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'
Falha no logon do usuário 'integracao'.
```

**ConnectionString**

```
    public const string CONNECTION_STRING = @"Data Source=ITVRS-D08;Initial Catalog=Teste; User Id=integracao;Password=integracao;";
    public const string DEPLOYMENT_CONNECTION_STRING = @"Data Source=ITVRS-D08;Initial Catalog=Teste; User Id=integracao;Password=integracao;";
```

**ConnectionString da aplicação que estava funcionando local**

```
    public const string CONNECTION_STRING = @"Data Source=ITVRS-r08;Initial Catalog=Integracao; User Id=integracao;Password=integracao;";
    public const string DEPLOYMENT_CONNECTION_STRING = @"Data Source=ITVRS-R08;Initial Catalog=Integracao; User Id=integracao;Password=integracao;";
```

O usuário 'integracao' foi criado no novo servidor com as mesmas permissões e tal. Não é problema de permissão, acredito, pois todas as permissões já foram concedidas.

A única diferença de ambiente é que o servidor local é SQL Server 2008 e no novo data center é SQL Server 2012.

Tem alguma coisa a ver com isso? O que mais posso verificar para conseguir rodar minha aplicação?

Comment: Você consegue logar com esse usuário pelo SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Em qualquer um dos servidores eu logo por windows authentication

Comment: mas consigo logar também por este usuário no SQL @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Comment: Ainda continuo tendo o problema...

Comment: No teste com o Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, você tem que entrar na máquina remoto pra testar? Ou você consegue fazer esse login pela sua máquina local? A mensagem devolvida pela aplicação no Visual Studio não esclarece nada.

Comment: Eu tentei com outra aplicação também e acontece a mesma coisa. No database local eu consigo rodar normalmente mas mudando a string de conexão para o datacenter com uma réplica do banco, usuário e etc dá esse erro para qualquer usuário que eu tente

Comment: Sim, o datacenter eu só acesso remotamente.

Comment: quando vc diz que consegue conectar via Management Studio, vc está conectando com seu usuario DBA ? no banco de dados ? o user da aplicação consegue conectar no database remoto com seu login e sua senha ? via management studio ?

Answer (score 4):

Verifique as configurações dos serviços TCP do SQL em:Todos os programas\SQL Managment\Ferramentas de Configuração\SQL Server Configurartion\Configuração de rede do SQL\Protocolos para MSSQLSERVER\TCP/IP na aba endereço ip deve conter IP Servidor e Habilitado:sim em todos, isso também implica diretamente na forma que o SQL foi instalado, como autoridades de sistema local, internet e etc.
Essa é a minha string de conexão e funciona perfeitamente em rede.Um teste eficaz é abrir o seu sql no seu computador e tentar conectar ao server pelo managment studio.

```
provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=banco;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=senha
```

Comment: quando vc diz que consegue conectar via Management Studio, vc está conectando com seu usuario DBA ? no banco de dados ?

Comment: o user da aplicação consegue conectar no database remoto com seu login e sua senha ? via management studio ?

Comment: Digo um primeiro teste pra saber se pelo menos o serviço em rede do SQL está funcionando pelo Management, senão não precisaria nem se preocupar com o erro que dá na aplicação.

Comment: Eu abro local no meu management studio o servidor sim, por windows authentication. Remotamente no servidor consigo conectar tanto por windows authentication quanto pelo login e senha.

Comment: Ainda com o problema PFVictor?

Answer (score 1):

Possivelmente a porta 1433 no seu servidor remoto não está aberta, ou o SQL Server remoto não está configurado para aceitar conexões remotas.

Para configurar acesso remoto no servidor, [siga os passos neste link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms191464.aspx).

Comment: um dos passos diz: "**marque ou desmarque** a caixa de seleção Permitir conexões remotas com este servidor"??

Comment: A caixa já estava marcada, ou seja, permitindo conexões remotas.

Comment: Veja o Firewall, então.

Comment: O que preciso verificar no firewall?

Comment: Veja se há uma exceção para a porta 1433, ou para o SQL Server mesmo.

Comment: Firewall tudo ok também. Não existe nenhuma exceção

Comment: Experimente agora conectar pelo SQL Server Management Studio da sua máquina no servidor remoto.

Comment: Conecta @Cigano

Comment: Continua o mesmo erro... com variações do descrito na pergunta e: " **Falha de logon do usuário 'AUTORIDADE NT\LOGON ANÔNIMO'.**"

Comment: Mas não pode ser login anônimo. Tem que ser aquele login "integracao".

Comment: Pois é... o usuário está como eu passei na pergunta. E agora independente do usuário que eu passe na connectionstring dá esse mesmo erro de Logon Anônimo

Comment: Você disse que não existe exceção, mas deve existir, a 1433 de saída e a 1433 de entrada, senão tiver, as crie.

Answer (score 0):

Você verificou se o servidor do banco de dados remoto permite acesso externo para o IP no qual sua aplicação está hospedada? Geralmente os servidores de banco de dados limitam acesso externo, tornando necessário que você adicione uma exceção para os IPs que você deseja que tenha acesso ao seu servidor.

Se este for o caso, siga os detalhes descritos nesta página para configurar seu servidor de homologação para permitir acesso remoto: http://www.systematiza.com.br/site/?page_id=837